# How to stretch main page content to fill the rest of the screen?

Tags: tailwind-css

I want to create a basic layout with a sticky navbar ( always visible ), a slot for the content of the route and a footer component below the page content.

[Playground for reproduction](https://play.tailwindcss.com/MRpQ1uAni1)

```
<!-- Lives in layout component -->
<nav class="sticky top-0 flex items-center justify-between border-b border-slate-200 bg-white py-6 px-8">
  <span class="text-2xl font-semibold text-slate-800">Logo</span>
  <button>toggle menu</button>
</nav>

<!-- Slot component ( renders router view ) -->
<section class="min-h-screen">Sample route content goes here</section>

<!-- Lives in layout component -->
<footer class="flex items-center justify-end space-x-8 border-t border-slate-200 py-6 px-8">footer links to the right side</footer>
```

I want to get rid of using `min-h-screen` for the section because the route content is smaller than the screen height. If that's the case, how can I tell it to use less height, e.g.

> screen height - navbar height - footer height

If the page content is larger than the screen height I have no need for `min-h-screen` so I'm looking for a flexible solution.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to create a container div with `min-h-screen`, then inside it you place as children: (i) another div containing the navbar and the content; and (ii) the footer.

The container div is styled with `flex`, `flex-col` and `justify-between` to keep the children elements apart (meaning the div with navbar and content stays at the top of the page, and the footer stays at the bottom).

```html
<!-- Lives in layout component -->
<div class="min-h-screen flex flex-col justify-between">
  <div>
    <nav class="sticky top-0 flex items-center justify-between border-b border-slate-200 bg-white py-6 px-8">
      <span class="text-2xl font-semibold text-slate-800">Logo</span>
      <button>toggle menu</button>
    </nav>

    <!-- Slot component ( renders router view ) -->
    <section>Sample route content goes here</section>
  </div>

  <!-- Lives in layout component -->
  <footer class="flex items-center justify-end space-x-8 border-t border-slate-200 py-6 px-8">footer links to the right side</footer>
</div>
```